# when hit enter go to next input no matter what the type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vuejs2

I have HTML code with some required inputs and ather is not 
here is my code

```js
$("input,select").bind("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input class='form-control input' type='text' name='{{$variables[2]}}' placeholder="{{trans('language.'.$variables[2])}}" required/> {{trans('language.'.$variables[2])}} *
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class='form-control input' type='text' name='{{$variables[3]}}' placeholder="{{trans('language.'.$variables[3])}}" required/> {{trans('language.'.$variables[3])}} *
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class='form-control input' type='text' name='{{$variables[4]}}' placeholder="{{trans('language.'.$variables[4])}}" /> {{trans('language.'.$variables[4])}}
    </li>
    <li>
      <select class='form-control input' name='{{$variables[5]}}' required>
  <option>{{trans('language.chose')}}</option>
  @foreach($units as $unit)
   <option value='{{$unit["id"]}}'>{{$unit['unit_name']}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select> {{trans('language.item_default_unit')}} *
    </li>
    <li>
      <select class='form-control input' name='{{$variables[6]}}' class='form-control'>
  <option>{{trans('language.chose')}}</option>
  @foreach($colors as $color)
   <option value='{{$color["id"]}}'>{{$color['color_name']}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select> {{trans('language.color')}}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class='form-control input' type='number' name='{{$variables[7]}}' placeholder="{{trans('language.'.$variables[7])}}" /> {{trans('language.'.$variables[7])}}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class='form-control input' type='number' name='{{$variables[8]}}' placeholder="{{trans('language.'.$variables[8])}}" /> {{trans('language.'.$variables[8])}}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class='form-control input' type='number' name='{{$variables[9]}}' placeholder="{{trans('language.'.$variables[9])}}" /> {{trans('language.'.$variables[9])}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

now when i hit enter i go to the next tow inputs they are required 
after that when the input type = text or number but its not required its skipped it .. 
i want it to go to the next input no matter if it required or not and now matter what the type of it 
also im using vuejs2 if it possible to do that in vuejs2 ill be thankful

Comment: I ran your code above and works fine in a stackoverflow snipplet. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: its working in the first tow inputs

Comment: It is going to all the inputs when I run it here....

Comment: I edited your question to make it runnable, test it out and see what I am talking about.